# Return dynamically generated data from URL

Tags: php, url, curl

I'm leveraging PHP to try and save the result I'm presented with when visiting a URL instead of having to choose 'Save As'.

I'm working with a URL that has a number of variables that a user can modify and once the user has chosen their options, the URL is concatenated for use but there seems to be no way to retrieve the data using `curl` or any of the `file` functions, however if the user were to manually click a link generated by my script or paste the URL into their browser, they are presented with a browser prompt to save the extentionless file.

I've been working with `curl` to try and download the return from the URL with no success and displaying `curl_getinfo` shows the following:

```
[url] => REMOVED-FOR-REASONS-?startDate=08-01-2015&endDate=09-01-2015&format=csv
[content_type] => 
[http_code] => 0
[header_size] => 0
[request_size] => 0
[filetime] => 0
[ssl_verify_result] => 0
[redirect_count] => 0
[total_time] => 0
[namelookup_time] => 0
[connect_time] => 0
[pretransfer_time] => 0
[size_upload] => 0
[size_download] => 0
[speed_download] => 0
[speed_upload] => 0
[download_content_length] => -1
[upload_content_length] => -1
[starttransfer_time] => 0
[redirect_time] => 0
[redirect_url] => 
[primary_ip] => 
[certinfo] => Array
    (
    )

[primary_port] => 0
[local_ip] => 
[local_port] => 0
```

I switched over to `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents` and the resulting file is nothing more than the HTML used to display the page you would see if you were creating the file at the destination URL as if the user never submitted the form; the corresponding file that the user would download is not returned.

As there is no file generated on the target server, the data I am trying to capture is just a return of the requested data in a format that can be saved, conveniently, with a csv extension, can I use `curl` or the `file` commands?

Comment: Can't you just use `$_GET` ?

Comment: what data structure does the remote page actually return? Not entirely clear what you are trying to do here

Comment: do you want to save the GET params as a CSV?

Comment: The data structure is proprietary, but is a dozen or so comma separated values as the data return is a sql result built off of the URL variables.

Comment: Does it require some string in the `USER_AGENT` field?

Comment: Added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");` to the `curl` function and get nothing new back.

Comment: You're never starting the query string in your URL; the `&` in `REMOVED-FOR-REASONS-&` should be a `?`, i.e., `REMOVED-FOR-REASONS-?etc`

Comment: @ScallioXTX That was just a typo in the example, everything is taken care of properly in the code. I've updated my example.